# What is the exact value of $\frac{1}{2}\ +\ \frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{4}\ +\ \frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{8}\ +\ \ldots\ ?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

What is the exact value of $\frac{1}{2}\ +\ \frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{4}\ +\ \frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{8}\ +\ \ldots\ ?$

Another way of writing this series is $\quad\displaystyle\sum_{k\text{ is a triangular number}}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^k.$

Since one definition of $\ e\ $ is  $\quad 1 + \frac{1}{1}\ +\ \frac{1}{1}\times\frac{1}{2}\ +\ \frac{1}{1}\times\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{3}\ +\ \ldots,\ $ it seems somewhat plausible that the value of the sum is related to $e.$

Comment: It isn't.  I do not believe a closed form exists in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: It's basically a theta function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function (see also Eq. 9 here https://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html ; take $z=0$ and $q = 1/\sqrt{2}$)

Comment: $0.64163256\ldots$. See [OEIS A190405](https://oeis.org/A190405)

Comment: Ok. Good to know I wasn't missing anything obvious.